# Alter table query working on Postgres 12 but not Postgres 11. syntax error near "("

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, postgresql-12

Error:

```
19:20:44.737 [info]  execute "ALTER TABLE listings\n       ADD COLUMN search_tsvector tsvector\n       GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('spanish', coalesce(title, '') || ' ' || coalesce(description, ''))) STORED;"
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42601 (syntax_error) syntax error at or near "("

    query: ALTER TABLE listings
       ADD COLUMN search_tsvector tsvector
       GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('spanish', coalesce(title, '') || ' ' || coalesce(description, ''))) STORED;
```

This query runs fine locally on my Postgres 12, but in my server where I can only use Postgres 11 it doesn't run successfully.

Can someone assist?

Answer (score 3):

Postgres 11 did not have generated columns, except for identity columns:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html